# FabricJS object coordinates relative to an image instead of whole canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I'm trying to create a small website using the FabricJS library, which adds additional features to the web canvas element.

My issue that I, however, have is that i want to resize the canvas (in red) so that it fills the whole webpage.
On this canvas, there is a background image (in green) where I'll create some drawings on (in orange, this could be lines, squares,...).

Now, I would like to export all drawings in a coordinate system **relative** to the image and not to the whole canvas, because it should be possible to freely move around and zoom in/out the image for an enhanced drawing experience.

My idea, on how to solve this, would be to calculate the image position relative to the canvas and subtract them from the drawings - but that includes a lot of calculation.. Maybe there is a more genius approach with FabricJS?

Moreover, how can i guarantee that my drawings move around and zoom in/out **with** the image, so that my drawings are always true to the image?

I've thought about this for days and came to the realization that i need input from the professionals.

[image]

Comment: calculate the image position relative to the canvas and subtract them from the drawings - but that includes a lot of calculation... sound like the proper way to me and no a subtraction is not "a lot of calculation" you write it once and the computer does it for you lightning fast

Comment: @HelderSepulveda well I'm just exploring to see if there is a more "natural, fabricjs" way than me reinventing the wheel. And what about then moving the drawing together with the image, while also keeping the aspect ratio and/or size true to the image?

Answer (score 1):

I think [toLocalPoint()](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#toLocalPoint) might help. Given an object `imageObj` and absolute coordinates `left` and `top` of your drawing, you can find the relative coordinates like this:

```
const abs = new fabric.Point(left, top)
const rel = imageObj.toLocalPoint(point, 'left', 'top')
console.log(rel.x, rel.y)
```

As for your second question: there is no easy way to "tie" two objects together, other than grouping them - and I assume you don't want to group them. Therefore, you would need to listen to all the appropriate events emitted by one object and make the adjustments to the other object in their handlers. To find out what events make sense to listen to in your case, see the [events demo](http://fabricjs.com/events).